# State passed through context returns undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm trying to make my context work properly.
I've added it and it works as it should if I pass a string as a property to the state. However, I want to pass a prop as the state.

So this works:

```
export class DataProvider extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      continent: props.continent,
    };
    this.updateState = this.updateState.bind(this);
  }

  updateState() {
    this.setState({ continent: this.props.continent});
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    console.log(this.props.continent);
    this.updateState();
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <DataContext.Provider value={{ state: this.state }}>
        {this.props.children}
      </DataContext.Provider>
    );
  }
}
```

But this does not work (results in undefined)

```
  this.state = {
      continent: this.props.continent,
    };
```

Results in "undefined" when I try to access it.

I get the prop from a component named "Africa", which does this:

```
const Africa = ({}) => {
  return (
    <div>
       <DataProvider continent={["Africa"]} /> 
........irrelevant code
```

It successfully passes to my DataProvider component.
But, as I stated, when I try to pass that as a property for my state, it results in "undefined".

```
class JumbotronPage extends Component {
  static contextType = DataContext;

  render() {
    console.log(this.context)
```

A(DataProvider), B(Africa), C(JumbotronPage)
I'm not sure if it's because A and B recognizes each other. 
B and C does not.

So whenever I access C from A, B gets re-rendered, resulting in giving C nothing as state. Does that make sense?

Please, forgive me for being very green and new to React. I hope I make some sense.

Thanks

Edit:
setState did not seem to work properly. I threw it into a componentDidMount, I can now set string-states, however, as soon as I pass my props to it, it's undefined.

Edit2:
This is part of my App.js:

```
<Route exact path="/Login" component={Login} />

            <Route exact path="/Jumbotron">
              <DataProvider>
                <JumbotronPage />
              </DataProvider>
            </Route>
            <Route exact path="/CreateNewMemories" component={renderForm} />
```

Edit3:
I created a gist, if someone has the time an patience to have a look at my abomination.

https://gist.github.com/kalleftw/e79412034eafd29a2e26b1af24149e67

Edi4:
Do I even need to set the state?

```
this.state = {
      continent: props.continent,
    };
```

This seems to work when I log it with componentDidMount.
However, as soon as I try to access the component "Jumbotron", the context there is undefined.

Comment: change `continent: this.props.continent` to `continent: props.continent`

Comment: also this is a fairly old way of using context. Are you stuck on an old version of react for some reason? -- here's a good article that came out recently on context https://kentcdodds.com/blog/how-to-use-react-context-effectively

Comment: Doing that results in undefined aswell.
No, I'm not stuck at all. This was the way I found easier to understand, so I figured that it's where I should start.

Thanks!

Comment: oh wait.. where did you make that change? I just noticed you have that line in two places. I mean in the constructor. in the`updateState` you should leave it as is (wthi `this.props`)

Comment: Alright. So I did, however, it still returns undefined. I did just as you said. Letting the constructor have "props.continent" and the updateState have "this.props.continent. I tried to add the this.setState to a componentWillMount, but it still returns undefined.

Comment: I'm actually not sure if it's my setState that causes the problem. It does not update state, even if I put in a string. But I'm not sure how to fix it.. Edit: I fixed setState, but it still returns undefined.

Answer (score 1):

The correct way to update the state is with `setState`, right, but it is a function. Use `this.setState({ ... })` not `this.setState = { ... }`

Comment: Thanks for your answer.
I updated my code. Still undefined, though.